# Ionic 2: loading external content inside the app

Tags: html, json, ionic-framework, external

I'm new to Ionic. My typescript file is like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-about',
 templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
   mypage: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
        this.http
  .get('http://localhost/xampp/')
  .map(response => response.text())
  .subscribe(html => this.mypage = html);
  }
}
```

Any URL, even in the same source, leads to an error like:
`EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null`
The error appear on either ionic serve in my pc or my phone. What am i supposed to do to solve?
I thought to load it as component too "templateUrl: 'somehtml'", but in future i'd like to load some json data in my apps. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are going to have a hard time tying to get a full url from a GET request. There are some serious security risks. I would be very surprised ,even if you do get it working, that it will be accepted by the app stores. If its your own codebase then you need to create an Api which will interact with the GET request

Comment: I have it (a SOAP and a REST webservice); this was just for learning purposes. What should be the route to follow? Is it different if i want to load a template or some json data or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself. This was a CORS issue, but i found almost no info about it on Ionic 2.
Answer lies in `ionic.config.json` file. You gotta add these lines to the json item:

```
"proxies": [
    {
        "path": "/virtualfolder",
        "proxyUrl": "http://www.externalsite.com"
    }
  ]
```

Now comes the real issue. Enough? No, of course. Back to my code, i should have done this:

```
this.http
  .get('virtualfolder/someresource.html')
  .map(response => response.text())
  .subscribe(html => this.mypage = html);
```

Ionic maps your external resource in the path you specified.
After noticing that, i had to solve some more issues that didn't have something to do with that, but it did what i wanted in the end, and i noticed how awesome is the anti-XSS policy. Hope i'll help someone.

Comment: Are you loading html and bind it to your app?

Comment: @AvishaiPeretz I intended to use this to get some JSON data, but it worked with html too

Comment: can I load only some part of html content?